# Tensorflow test problems

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently training a SSD model and the `train.py` runs fine. However, when starting the `test.py` in a new tab, I get the following error message:

```
from pycocotools import coco
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycocotools'

I had a similar error before, but I thought I had fixed it by installing  `pycocotools` (therefore `train.py` runs).

Any ideas about what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using python 3.x?

Usually something like this occurs if you try to install a package via pip2, and not pip3.

Running `pip3 install pycocotools` should do the trick.

If you are running python 2.x, running `pip install pycocotools` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu :

`pip3 install pycocotools`

On Windows:

`pip install git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#egg=pycocotools^&subdirectory=PythonAPI`